# Navigator.pop() is not closing showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my bottom dialog

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              isScrollControlled: true,
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return BottomDialog();
              });)}
 class BottomDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomDialogState createState() => _BottomDialogState();
}

class _BottomDialogState extends State<BottomDialog> {
  Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Manage Receipt");
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);

        @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
      // height: 300.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Wrap(
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                             Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                              child: Text('CREATE RECEIPT'))),
                 
                ],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
         
        },
```

I am implementing showModalBottomSheet in my Flutter application. Everything works perfectly but when I click the button it's not closing the bottom sheet.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Column` under `Form` needs `height` constraints. I would suggest wrapping it with a `SizedBox` like so:

```yaml
   Form(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text('CREATE RECEIPT'))),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

With this change the code works perfectly, and the button pops the dialog.

Comment: I don't want to give height for my dialog. the height will be increased dynamically based on the content in dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );      
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you indicate, by way of an explanation in this post, why this is an answer to the question?